# Laptop Brightness dims when charger is unplugged(no solution)?

Tags: display, dell-inspiron, brightness, display-settings, charging

Hello yesterday i bought DELL Inspiron 15 (3542) win 8.1. And noticed that if charger is plugged on, screen becomes brighter, and after unplugging dimmer. Of course i tried adjust screen brightness, I've tried changing all power plan settings, changed advanced power settings to max. tryed go to bios but there was nothing about brightness. i tried use brightness buttons on keyboard no matter if charger is plugged in or not the bright bar is still set to full, however the bright difference still exist. the bright difference then charger is on are about 4%-6% . then i pull out the charger the screen becomes darken in few sec. and i noticed that after closing and opening the led(then computer is using only battery power) at the start screen is same bright as with charger plugged in. My sister have older Dell laptop(bought 4years ago) and for her the bright difference was about 50% but i repaired that through Bios. So how i can fix that uncomfortable issue?

Comment: Is it slowly dimming over a few seconds?  Or just after a few seconds, immediately dropping into the new brightness?  I'm trying to determine if you just haven't found the power savings settings, or if there is something wrong with the bulb/inverter.

Comment: yap it is slowly dimming. its seems like there should be an option in settings. but i tryed all options few times. maybe there is some hiden options or so?

Comment: in the settings everything is maxed. it seems like then charger is plugged in, screen becomes like 5% brighter or so. but i checked all parameters.

Comment: I don't know if the newer Dells have this automatic dim smoothing, but the last few models I used didn't.  Because of this, I suspect you actually have a voltage regulation problem.  Something else to try... Drain the battery down until it is completely dead.  Boot the laptop on AC power and check its brightness.  With it on, plug in the battery and see if the screen dims at all.

Answer (score 10):

I know that this question is 2 years old, but this issue still pertains to this day, and might still be of relevance to some people. I'll be sharing a solution that I found. I'll guess that OP has a laptop with an AMD GPU/iGPU. Basically the graphics driver is causing the screen to dim. To fix this, right click your desktop, then (probably at the top of the menu), click 'AMD Catalyst Control Centre' Then, under 'Power', click 'PowerPlaytm'. Within the new menu that is brought up, look at the bottom where it says 'Enable Vari-Brighttm'. Untick it. Your problem should be solved, as was mine.

Comment: "I'll guess that OP has a laptop with an AMD GPU/iGPU" You guessed wrong. Why didn't you bother to checked the spec? "Graphics adapter
NVIDIA GeForce 820M - 2048 MB". So your answer does not apply to the question.

Comment: I have amd and this does not work.

Comment: It's working for me. In my case Windows Update installed the AMD drivers and it was causing the issue. Thank you

Comment: It's working for me. In my case Windows Update installed the AMD drivers and it was causing the issue. Thank you

Comment: This helped me with a brand new AMD-based Lenovo IdeaPad 5 - if you don't have the AMD Radeon Software installed, you'll need to install it in order to turn the 'VariBright' feature off.

Comment: Asus TUF 2022 laptop as above comment. Switching off Vari-Bright in "AMD software: Adrenalin Edition" solved the issue. You might need to plug and unplug laptop again or/and close the software for the change to take effect though.

Answer (score 4):

The computer is designed to do that when it's unplugged.  You can change the behavior if you don't like it.  This link should have everything you need.

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5464-power-plan-settings-change-windows-8-a.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: that was first things what i have done.:/ the bright difference is very low, but for my eye it is very uncomfortable.

Comment: Does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you own a computer with amd graphics. You will have to disable "vari-bright"

1)go to amd radeon settings
2) go to advanced
3) energy/battery-> disable vari-bright

Comment: More detail on this by chance?

Answer (score 1):

It's a very late answer but it could possibly help someone...

This is one of the complex problems which has irritated me for very long and I can guarantee that one who has not experienced the problem cannot understand it fully.

I first found this problem on my laptop (Dell 3543). The problem is when you start your laptop unplugged, the screen is very low in contrast and in addition to that the brightness changes dynamically based on the content it displays.

Some people call it **Intel Display Power Saving Technology**'s Fault many confuse it with **adaptive brightness** but the real problem is related with the BIOS.

**Few Working Solutions:-**

1. Uninstall Display Driver
2. Update your BIOS

In my case however I re-installed an older bios from vendor.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but I solved this, 
here is instruction,

1. right click on desktop and click Graphics Properties.
2. click power
3. click on battery
4. click maximum performance and apply and done.

you will see the display will 100% bright.

Thanks, Hilal

Comment: Screen still dims.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am using hp pavilion notebook and for the operating system, I'm using windows 10. It basically happens because of graphics driver. I have Intel HD graphics card as a built-in graphics card. On the Desktop, Right Click and go to the Graphics Properties option. Then go to the power option. As my screen was getting dimmer when on battery, I chose On Battery menu from the left side. Then choose maximum performance and make sure you disable "Display Power Saving Technology". I think this option is causing the issue. It solves the problem for me. Hopefully yours too. :)

Comment: Thanks - this method is working if anyone is using Intel HD graphics.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**: click on battery icon at bottom of desktop, where time & date appears. after click go to more options on battery icon, then create your own plan by name PLAN 1 or PLAN 2 as you wish. then set all settings like battery, power and other option to NEVER. then click on next.

Now your laptop screen will not be dim if you unplug the charger.

Comment: Why bother repeating what was already stated in older answers? It did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 100`

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem with the current graphics settings. Try this,

Right click on Desktop → Select graphics properties → click on Power → Under left hand top side select On Battery → Under Graphics power plans
Select  Balanced Mode or Maximum Performance and Disable Display power Saving Technology.

thanks...

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a solution for his also, for my laptop : TOSHIBA SATELLITE L50-B-14P running on Windows 10 Home. My laptop runs on an Intel HD Graphics 4400.

To resolve:

1) Go to Desktop

2) Right click on desktop

3) Select Graphics Properties (the Intel programme should boot up)

4) Select Power from the icons presented

5) In the left column, select "On Battery"

6) Ensure the setting is set to:
- Maximum performance
- DISABLE Power Saving Technology

7) Apply the setting, and see your screen bright up :)

Please note: your laptop run time might not be as long as it was in previous setting.

Note 2) If your intel HD control screen does not start at step 3, please ensure you have the same graphics card as me, and check if you have your drivers installed properly. Further, check intel website for the graphics control programme.